# Голосуйте одразу та багато! / Vote early and often!

Tags: discussion, participation, info

*Цей допис — переклад статті [Vote early and often!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often)* з сайту Meta.Tex.SE.
This post is a translation of the linked article at Meta.Tex.SE. The original English text is below.

---

Я — модератор сайту MathOverflow, і це «питання» є, власне, непрошеною порадою, яка базується на нашому досвіді запуску сайту MathOverflow.

> Ми маємо заохочувати кожного голосувати позитивно і якомога більше!

Кожний сайт мережі Stack Exchange рано чи пізно приходить до деякого «базового рівня» голосування — іншими словами, деякої очікуваної кількості голосів, які отримують питання кожного рівня якості. (Цей ефект проявляється, коли хтось бачить хороше запитання, яке вже отримало деяку кількість голосів, і думає до себе: «я б і проголосував за це запитання, але там вже й так достатньо голосів»).

Саме зараз ми можемо вплинути на цей «базовий рівень», заохочуючи високу кількість голосів. Ми встановлюємо стандарти, які потім розповсюджуватимуться на подальше життя сайту.

(На MathOverflow ми завжди були доволі активними з самого початку, прямо заохочуючи найперше коло користувачів голосувати одразу та багато. Можете порівняти статистики, і ви побачите, що рівень голосування за середньостатистичне запитання на MathOverflow є набагато вищим, аніж на будь-якому іншому сайті сімейства SE 1.0).

Уточнення: причина, чому ми хочемо бачити високий рівень голосування, полягає у тому, що багато голосів являє собою більший відгук тим, хто надає якісний контент для сайту.

---

## [English](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often)

I'm a moderator from MathOverflow, and this "question" is actually unsolicited advice, based on our experience from the initial launch of MathOverflow.

> We should encourage everyone to vote positively as often as possible!

Every Stack Exchange site will eventually end up with a different "base level" of voting --- that is, the expected number of upvotes for a question of a given level of excellence. (This effect occurs because people see a good question, but already with a certain number of votes, and think "oh, I would have upvoted this, but it already has enough".)

It's easy for us to affect this "base level" by encouraging high levels of upvoting now. We're setting the standards, and this really will have an effect.

(On MathOverflow, we were very active about this early on, specifically encouraging all the initial round of users to vote early and often. You can compare statistics, and see that the average vote total for a MathOverflow question is much higher than on any of the other SE 1.0 sites.)

In case it's not obvious: the rationale for wanting this base level to be high is that it provides better positive feedback to good contributors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is announcement, not a genuine question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57396/discussion-between-bytebuster-and-sasha).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Додам від себе: пишуть що на сайтах stackexchange є досить великий дисбаланс в оцінюванні відповідей і запитаннь.

Люди більше голосують за гарні відповіді, але набагато менше голосують за гарні питання. Без питаннь нема відповідей, тому гарні питання також треба підтримувати.

Особисто для себе я випрацював такий критерій: якщо я відповідаю на питання - значить воно мене зацікавило - значить воно заслуговує на позитивний голос.