# Should we ask new users to register on at least one other SE community

Tags: discussion

Would it be cheating if we advised the newcomers to join other communities on SE? This way we could get more 200rep users (active (even if all you do is upvote) usage of any other community gives you 100 points of reputation). Is it significant at all? Or should we concentrate on getting more questions per day? I know quality comes first, but let's take care about both `q'`s.

Comment: Why are mentioning 200-point reputation? What does 200-point reputation bring?

Comment: Here is a [list of privileges](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/).

Comment: Ah, I understood, you mean [these numbers](//area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language).

Comment: I'd [not concentrate on these numbers too much](//meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/147/4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We are not *that* badly in need of 200+ rep users :-)
2. How can we *„ask”*? By writing a post on Meta? A new user would not even see it;
3. Earning a 200 rep is easy by writing, say, five posts (provided that we have a healthy **voting pattern**; as of today, [we don't](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all));

Let's better focus on:

1. Creating a quality content,

   - that makes users return
   - and subsequently inspire them writing their *own* Q&A posts;
2. Encouraging good posts by [**voting**](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17/).

P.S. `-1` at Meta [means disagreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites) (e.g., "I prefer we do it the other way") and it does not affect one's site reputation. :-)

Comment: I agree. It was just a thought that popped up.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen the association bonus become a make-or-break issue for a community so I don't think there's a need to press the issue beyond a meta post to raise awareness (like this).

But it would *not* be appropriate to go around prodding users to join other communities in comments or any other methods generally available in the main Q&A or other unrelated meta posts.

Posts are used to answer questions; comments are used to ask for clarification or to suggest improvements for the post. But we don't want comments and other Q&A features to become social-media outlets for whatever conversation you want to have with a user. We have chat rooms for that, but even then… read the room — constantly interjecting reminders to join other communities randomly into whatever conversation folks are engaged in will likely become annoying fast.

Comment: thank you for your response, that's why I asked.
I agree we'd better concentrate on good questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this suggestion won't work even if all already given answers were incorrect.

This is because [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141649/196120) (100 exp. points) is given when one of the linked accounts already have 200 exp. points.

So, the newcomer has to be already quite experienced StackExchange user.

I think it makes much sense to gain 200 exp. points on this site, than to join some other site on the network, gain 200 exp. points there to get 100 exp. points here for free. Especially if you are interested primarily in Ukrainian language.