# Чи цей сайт під загрозою унаслідок неактивності? Is this site endangered due to inactivity?

Tags: discussion, statistics, recent-activity

Наскільки мені відомо, приблизно у 2017 році Stack Exchange відмовилася від практики закриття сайтів через неактивність.

Щоправда, у 2018 було закрито сайт Personal Productivity. На момент закриття сайт мав [0.4 запитання на день](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296?phase=beta), і цього виявилося недостатньо для того, щоб сайт вважався активним.

Ukrainian Language наразі має [0.1 запитання на день](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001?phase=beta), що у чотири рази гірше, ніж у Personal Productivity у найгірші його часи.

Якість (невидалених) дописів постійно знижується, гілки коментарів не чистяться, [модератори не виконують свою роботу](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/269/8).

2½ роки тому я [запитував](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/235/8), як ми можемо покращити активність, і за ці 2½ роки запитання отримало аж цілих 32 перегляди, що я особисто вважаю провалом.

---

**Запитання:** яким є статус цього сайту з точки зору *сучасного бачення* власників мережі Stack Exchange та Community Moderators?

Comment: Чесно — я особисто не знаю.

Comment: @Sasha, власне, запитання і було адресоване, у першу чергу, до модераторів. Бо хто, як не ви, маєте доступ до Teachers' Lounge, наприклад. Або хто, як не ви, маєте перейматися рекламуванням сайту.

Comment: Так, ми маємо доступ до певних ресурсів, до яких звичайні користувачі доступу не мають. (Не певен, що я знаю, що таке Teachers' Lounge, але деякі недоступні звичайним користувачам розділи бачу.) Однак я не бачив, що там піднімали такі теми, і, якщо чесно, не хочу піднімати сам (бо боюся, що можу, звернувши увагу на факт низької відвідуваності цього сайту, погіршити цим становище).

Comment: Щодо рекламування — якщо чесно, не бачу, як функції модератора перетинаються з рекламуванням (модератор має, умовно кажучи, слідкувати за порядком). На початку існування сайту я активно рекламував його від свого імені — потім втомився; можливо, дарма; можливо, це мій моральний обов'язок як людини, що розпочала це все (але точно не як модератора).